# Can I define an action on file upload when using ipywidgets FileUpload widget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipython, jupyter

I want to create an event off the uploading of a file with `widgets.FileUpload` same as I would do with an `widgets.Button` using the `.on_click(some_function)`. Is there a way to do something like this

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def do_something_with_file(fu):

    content = fu.data[0].decode('utf-8') 
    # doing something with the file content and get some string output
    return 'some string'

str_file_upload = widgets.FileUpload(accept='.txt', multiple=False)
str_file_upload.on_upload(do_something_with_file)
```

Comment: After working with widgets for a while, I found the easiest way (for me) to do this is by subclassing the widget class and listening to a change via the relevant tartlet. In this case this would mean creating a class `ActionFileUpload(widgets.FileUpload)` and adding a method wrapped with `@observe(''_counter''). This new class will run whatever method appears under `@observe(''_counter'').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can observe the change in _counter

Example:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
uploader = widgets.FileUpload()
display(uploader)

def on_upload_change(change):
    print(change)

uploader.observe(on_upload_change, names='_counter')
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is not working anymore, with ipywidgets version >= 8.0.2:

```
TypeError: No such trait: FileUpload._counter
```

Instead observe the change in `value`:

Example:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
uploader = widgets.FileUpload()
label = widgets.Label("")

def on_upload_change(change):
    label.value = "Loaded"

uploader.observe(on_upload_change, names='value')

display(uploader, label)
```